Simulate typewriter-like backspace behavior (overlapping characters)
I'd like to build a simulator for an old LGP-30 computer. This includes in- and output on an - also simulated - Friden Flexowriter typewriter.
One of the characteristics of the typewriter is, that when you press the backspace key, it just moves the print head one position to the left (or, to be precise, it moves the drum one position to the right), without erasing the last printed character. That allows it to print overlapping characters. For example, if you press O, backspace, /, you would get a "Ø" character. Likewise, if you want underlined text, you could type "text", then 4x backspace and 4x _.
The best I could achieve so far is this CSS class:
  .bs {
    letter-spacing: -0.6em;
  }

This lets me write html like <span class="bs">O</span>/ to get the desired output. The drawback is, that I'd need to have an array of overlapping characters for every position in the output div, so I can generate the html for overlapping characters.
For example, for the underlined word "text", the generated output would look like this:
<span class="bs">t</span>_
<span class="bs">e</span>_
<span class="bs">x</span>_
<span class="bs">t</span>_

What I'd like to have would be something like this:
text&bksp;&bksp;&bksp;&bksp;____

Or some other substitution for a backspace character that leads to letters being painted overlapping.
Do you know any CSS-tricks, or maybe some typescript code or a node.js library, that helps me implementing that behavior without too much struggle? The font will be a monospace font, so all I need is a "negative space symbol" or a "move the cursor 0.6em left" command.

There may be a better solution but you could count how many backspace are typed (x) to add the next x characters typed into a position:absolute div on top of the "normal" one.

This seems to work quite nice. I tested it with a span and position: relative like this: <p>Test: OOOO<span style="position: relative; left:-2.4em">////. End test.</span></p> and it shows the expected output. I'll try if this is easier to handle than the other answer. Thank you.

You can generate the output HTML from a simple input string containing \b characters.
I would stack the letters using a grid, placing all children in the same cell.
Full example:
<script>
    let text = 'hello world\b\b\b\b\b_____';

    $: positions = (() => {
        let positions = [];
        let current = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
            if (text[i] == '\b') {
                current--;
                continue;
            }

            positions[current] ??= [];
            positions[current].push(text[i]);
            current++;
        }

        return positions;
    })();
</script>

<div class="root">
    {#each positions as list}
        <span class="pos">
            {#each list as letter}<span class="letter">{letter}</span>{/each}
        </span>
    {/each}
</div>

<style>
    .root { font-family: monospace; }
    .pos { display: inline-grid; }
    .pos > * { grid-area: 1 / 1; }
    .letter { white-space: pre; }
</style>

REPL

Hi brunnerh, thank you for your answer. This resembles my initial idea to have an array of letters for each position. The backspace works as intended, but newlines won't work anymore. I could add an array of lines, containing your array of positions, containing an array of letters, but I feel like it's a bit too much overhead to have each letter wrapped into two spans. I'll give it a try anyway. Thank you

I fiddled around with the REPL and ended up with this: REPL. Works great. Let's see if this is still performant when it is fed with single letters by an Observable that represents the Computer.
